# Jira How to add issues to a version

Tags: jira

I have a project the we've been testing using Jira. We just found the versions feature and created one. However I cannot find any documentation on adding existing or new issues to a version.

Please can someone shine a light over here. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I have searched for those default versions and cannot find them. I suspect we have a dodgy install of Jira. Might be worth it to reinstall. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the version of JIRA I use, I can add an issue to a version by editing the issue and setting "Fix Version/s" to the version you want to use. We do have a fairly customised project, though so it may be different for you.

We also have Greenhooper installed, and can drag and drop issues to version in the planning board.

Answer (score 5):

There are two version fields in JIRA by default. Fix Version and Affects versions. You should see those when you edit an issue, unless you have disabled them. You can add an issue to a version by selecting those field appropriately.

In Affects Versions you would enter the version where the problem exists and in Fix Version you would enter the version where the problem was (or will be) fixed.